# Cakephp: Why delete custom query is not working in app_controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I write below code in beforeFilter in aap_controller.

```
$this->query('delete * from suggest_debate_tags where suggest_debate_id = 0');
```

Error:

```
Call to undefined method UsersController::query()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppController class extends Controller class which is the base for Controllers. `query` is a part of the model so `$this->query()` will not work. You need to put the query() call in a model and call the model from your AppController.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution

I write below code in beforeFilter in aap_controller.

```
App::import('Model','SuggestDebateTag');

$cnt_tag_arr = $this->SuggestDebateTag->find('count',array ( "SuggestDebateTag.suggest_debate_id" => 0));

if($cnt_tag_arr > 0)
{

        $conditions = array ( "SuggestDebateTag.suggest_debate_id" => 0);
        $this->SuggestDebateTag->deleteAll($conditions);

}
```

And I write below code in users_controller.php

```
var $uses = array('SuggestDebateTag');
```

Its work fine.

Comment: What you're essentially doing is that you're clearing the `suggest_debat_tags` table *every time a request comes in*. Are you sure you want to do that?